# Running pm2 on Elastic Beanstalk in cluster mode

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I've been trying to run pm2 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk's node web service environment but without luck. I start up the express api via: `./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start server.js -i 0` but the server never comes out of a Degraded state. I can run this same command locally just fine. I have ssh'd into the aws instance and looked in the logs, but I don't see any errors. It would be a big help if I could chat with someone that has successfully run pm2 on eb via cluster mode.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to use PM2 on Beanstalk: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/use-pm2-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully deploy pm2 on aws elastic beanstalk, it has more than one way to achieve.
You may either add an installation command to the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file for pm2 global installation or simply install pm2 into your app and follow the instruction of the link below (recommended way).

https://gist.github.com/Unitech/4c8ea564aa8bf0a389c5

As for the first method, in your `config.yml` file, simply add the following line(the link above doesn't require this) :

```
container_commands:
    0_install_pm2:
        command: "npm install pm2 -g"
```

You need to manually handcode the start command for your app with this method.